# PowerShell PSBoundParameters handling no value provided

Tags: powershell, parameters

For my script I have some parameters like such:

```
[Alias("f")]
[string]$file
```

When the user enters this at command-line: "./script.ps1 -f"

It comes up with an error >"Missing an argument for parameter...."
I would like to handle this error myself, the default error is technical, and messy.

I would like to make it user friendly and readable, anyway?
Every suggestion I have read has said to make it Mandatory.

But it is NOT a mandatory command, what I am trying to accomplish is if someone provides the parameter tag (AKA "-file"), but fails to provide a value for it.

Comment: `./script.ps1` is the way to run it _without_ a value for `-f` (i.e. don't even specify the `-f`)

Comment: @gvee Yes, I know but a user/customer might not know that, and enter "-f" with no value, and in that case I want to provide a custom error message.

Comment: I believe that error is coming from the PS parser seeing an issue, not your code seeing an issue, but I'm not positive. If its coming from your script, then maybe a trap would work. edit: tried it with a trap, but its coming from the parser before the trap gets loaded.

Comment: Yea, and if you put the trap above the Param() block, it doesn't error out due to the invalid parameter, but then it errors out because param isn't the first call in the file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `[AllowNull()]` paremeter attribute then check and handle your self.

[Advanced Fuction parameter validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-5.1#allownull-validation-attribute)

```
[Cmdletbinding()]
Param
(
    [Alias("f")]
    [AllowNull()]
    [string]$file
)
Begin
{
    If($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('file') -and -not $file)
    { 
       Write-error 'ouch my user friendly error'
    }
}
Process{}
End{}
```

Note: the begin, process, end blocks are not needed but are a good standard to follow. Read more about them [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh413265.aspx) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods?view=powershell-5.1).

The downside is this still requires a `$null` or `''` parameter value to be passed.

If you start to look into this there are tons of posts about people attempting a similar goal.

[1 - passing-null-to-a-mandatory-parameter-to-a-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25459799/passing-null-to-a-mandatory-parameter-to-a-function)

[2 - PS Git Issue - 4616](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4616)

[3 - PS Git Issue - 4208](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4208)

[4 - powershell-param-statement-error-trap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20403009/powershell-param-statement-error-trap)

[5 - alternative-to-throwing-param-exceptions-in-powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022170/alternative-to-throwing-param-exceptions-in-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is using the `[Switch]` parameter. Switch parameters are parameters with no parameter value. They're effective only when they're used and have only one effect.

You can verify your script's needs with `get-help`. In your case it would show something like this:

```
get-help .\script.ps1
script.ps1 [[-file] <Object>]
```

But if you defining your parmeters like this:

```
Param
(
    [Alias("f")]
    [Switch]$file
)
```

`get-help` will now show that no object is needed:

```
get-help .\script.ps1
script.ps1 [-file]
```

A complete example would look something like this:

```
Param
(
    [Alias("f")]
    [Switch]$file
)
If($file) { 
    Write-Host '-f Switch enabled'
}
Else {
    Write-Host 'Missing -f Switch'
}
```

You can now call you script like `.\script.ps1 -file` or like `.\script.ps1 -f` and the output in the console would be '-f Switch enabled'